# How to make an alias that will sum a column of a file in my cshrc

Tags: linux, shell, unix, csh

I was wondering how I can make an alias in my .cshrc that will sum a column of my choosing of a file that I give it.

for example:
if text.txt was:

```
a b 3
a c 2
b c 1
```

```
sumcolumn 3 text.txt
```

would return 6

I think that I can use !:1 and !:2 for my user inputs right?

Here is what I am trying right now:

```
alias sumcolumn "awk \'{SUM+=\$\!:1}END{print SUM}\' \!:2"
```

I think I am not escaping something correctly.
When I source my .cshrc I get a error:

```
Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters.
```

I have already manually tried using the awk command in the shell:

```
awk '{SUM+=$3}END{print SUM}' test.txt
```

and it works. What am I missing?

Comment: Do it in a script rather than an alias.

Comment: You don't need to escape single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias sumcolumn 'awk '\''{ k += $3 }END{print k}'\'''
```